# Deshabilitar un enlace de formulario después de que éste sea llenado

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html5, css3

Tengo varios formularios que están ordenados en una página
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando entro a un formulario y lo termino de llenar y enviar para que se guarde a una base de datos. Quisiera que se me muestre desabilitado

Con tan solo algunos ejemplos, me sería de gran ayuda.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Cuando enviamos los formularios cambia de pantalla o se queda en la misma pantalla?

Comment: Un poco de código vendría bien a esta pregunta

Comment: Francisco Romero, se queda en la misma pantalla solo aparece un mensaje que el formulario esta completo

Answer (score 1):

Usualmente lo que se hace es que al darle click desabilitas el boton de submit con algun javascript que asigne la propiedad disabled=true al boton. Esto lo puedes hacer con jquery

Comment: `$("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");`

Answer (score 0):

Bastaría con **deshabilitar** el elemento que genera el envío del formulario (por ejemplo, un botón)

En **jQuery** sería algo como:

```
$(function()
{
  $('#idFormulario').submit(function(){
    $("#idBotonSubmit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    return true;
  });
});
```